# Cannot start windows 7 in virtualbox under ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

As the title says, I cannot start the windows 7 in vitualbox. I followed [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/how-to-install-windows-7-in-virtualbox-guide-hatryst) tutorial. I have already mounted the `windows 7 .iso` file in the storage tab. Now when I start the machine. I get the following error:

```
Fatal: No bootable medium found. System halted !
```

Where have I made mistake ? Please guide me. Am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as my operating system.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, and your question has nothing to do with programming. I suggest you post it to superuser.com or serverfault.com instead.

Comment: OK.. Thanks for informing.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Tab "System" -> "Motherboard" you can choose your "Boot Order".

- Make sure that "CD/DVD" is enabled
- Set "CD/DVD" to the top of the List

The virtual maschine should now load the Windows Image.

Comment: Nope. Error: `Fatal: Could not read from the boot menu. System halted !`